# AudioKit exportAsynchronously fails after changing input device

Tags: macos, audiokit

I need to make an ability to change input device for record on the fly while program is running (between recording sessions, not in recording process).
Here is the code that, i suppose, have to do that. But when im trying to change input device, AKNodeRecorder records nothing (duration always 0) and after trying to call exportAsynchronously on recorder.audioFile i always get an following error:

[central] 54:   ERROR:    >avae> AVAudioFile.mm:37: AVAudioFileImpl: error 2003334207

Tried to change almost all, but nothing has an effect. Here is the code that changes input device.

```
func setupRecordingChain(_ deviceIndex: Int = 0)
{
    AudioKit.stop()
    setupInputDevice(for: deviceIndex)

    self.micMixer = AKMixer(self.mic)
    self.micBooster = AKBooster(self.micMixer)
    self.micBooster.gain = 0

    do {
        self.recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: self.micMixer)
    }
    catch {
        //catch error
    }

    self.mainMixer = AKMixer(self.micBooster)

    AudioKit.output = self.mainMixer
    AudioKit.start()
}

private func setupInputDevice(for deviceIndex: Int)
{
    guard let inputDevices = AudioKit.inputDevices else { return }
    let inputDevice = inputDevices[deviceIndex]

    do {
        try self.mic.setDevice(inputDevice)
    } catch { 
        //catch error 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too surprised because input devices are difficult to deal with.  Just FYI there was a similar error reported here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088594/osstatus-error-2003334207-when-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: Yeah, i've seen it. So there is nothing wrong in my code changing input logic?